# HA Proxy Stick-table and tcp-connection configuration

Tags: haproxy

am using HA Proxy HA-Proxy version 1.4.18 2011/09/16 I am trying to insert the following into /etc/init.d/haproxy.cfg file

```
# Use General Purpose Couter (gpc) 0 in SC1 as a global abuse counter
# Monitors the number of request sent by an IP over a period of 10 seconds
stick-table type ip size 1m expire 10s store gpc0,http_req_rate(10s)
tcp-request connection track-sc1 src
tcp-request connection reject if { src_get_gpc0 gt 0 }

# Table definition  
stick-table type ip size 100k expire 30s store conn_cur(3s)
# Allow clean known IPs to bypass the filter
tcp-request connection accept if { src -f /etc/haproxy/whitelist.lst }
# Shut the new connection as long as the client has already 10 opened
tcp-request connection reject if { src_conn_cur ge 10 }
tcp-request connection track-sc1 src
```

I get the following error:

```
[ALERT] 256/113143 (4627) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:36] : stick-table: unknown argument 'store'.
[ALERT] 256/113143 (4627) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:37] : unknown argument 'connection' after 'tcp-request' in proxy 'http_proxy'
[ALERT] 256/113143 (4627) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:38] : unknown argument 'connection' after 'tcp-request' in proxy 'http_proxy'
[ALERT] 256/113143 (4627) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:41] : stick-table: unknown argument 'store'.
[ALERT] 256/113143 (4627) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:43] : unknown argument 'connection' after 'tcp-request' in proxy 'http_proxy'
[ALERT] 256/113143 (4627) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:45] : unknown argument 'connection' after 'tcp-request' in proxy 'http_proxy'
[ALERT] 256/113143 (4627) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:46] : unknown argument 'connection' after 'tcp-request' in proxy 'http_proxy'
[ALERT] 256/113143 (4627) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg 
[WARNING] 256/113143 (4627) : Proxy 'http_proxy': in multi-process mode, stats will be limited to process assigned to the current request.
[ALERT] 256/113143 (4627) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
[fail]
```

Could you please tell me what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Storing data in stick-tables only appeared in haproxy 1.5-dev, not 1.4. You should try the latest 1.5-dev12. BTW if you're on 1.4, you should upgrade to 1.4.22 which fixes a number of bugs since your one-year-old 1.4.18.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely look into it.